# SpEL and properties files

Tags: spring, properties, thymeleaf, spring-el

I'd like to format my properties and then display it on page using thymeleaf.
Let's asume this is how properties file looks like:

```
text.test=aBcDeFgHiJk
text.test_2=PovcxzKSADmc!@
```

Because i use Spring's Internationalization and localization when I want to display it in *.html file i use `#{text.test}`.  However in this case I'd like to invoke method toUpperCase() on my properties (or any diffrent method that Thymeleaf makes possible to use on strings) and then display what that methord returned. Is there any way to achieve it? Basically I want to get `ABCDEFGHIJK` instead of `aBcDeFgHiJk` without creating thrd variable in properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#messages` maybe?

```
${#messages.msg('text.test').toUpperCase()}
```